# calculating in odoo xml view

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14

is it possible to calculate variables in odoo(direct in the xml template)?

Example:

```
<field name="price"/>
<field name="log"/>

if price > 20
do something

if price <= 20
do something
```

or

```
price + log
do something
```

I‘ll calculate direct in the xml template.

Are operators available in the xml view? For example, plus, minus, greater than, less than, etc.? I could read something in the documentation regarding qweb, however that does not work for me.

a quick example…

`<t t-if="price > 20"> do something ....... </t>`

and then translate the > into special characters like > - because xml has problems to read the > - but this does not work for me…

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: please put some more description for understandability

Comment: @AndyBright: It's usually a good idea to update your initial question with the information, not put it into a comment :) .

Comment: What do you want to do with "do something"? Can you please get into more detail what you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: I just want to use a span class to indicate that a certain amount has been reached, for example via bootstrap badges (success, alert, warning). `<span class="badge badge-primary">okay</span>`

Comment: It works now! The solution is to use the `&lt; (<), &amp; (&), &gt; (>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&lt; (<), &amp; (&), &gt; (>)` in the xml template.

```
<t t-if="price &gt; 20"> do something ....... </t>
```